# Multiple font sizes - Javascript/jQuery typing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple typing effect, as Illustrated here:  http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonbroadhurst/fzf70ttg/9/

My issue is that as the large text is typed it moves the whole line up and down.

Is it possible to keep the text all on the same level as multiple fonts styles and sizes are added? (i.e. as large fonts are added the smaller text does not move vertically)

I have tried to use a `position: relative` wrapper div and then `position: absolute` to keep everything on the same line, but this did not work.

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.text-box {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I would rather not use any type of plugin and would prefer a coded solution.

Comment: Looks like it jumpes up a line when it types the spaces, but the solution, hm...

Comment: Seems to work OK for me on Firefox but not on Chrome :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a line height so it won't jump:

```
p { line-height: 75px; }
```

With the box model, the browser will calculate the height dynamically according to text size. Putting a hard size on the element will prevent this.